# What causes my keyboard shortcuts to be disabled on startup?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using latest Karmic Koala 9.10. I upgraded from 9.04, whenever I reboot I have to go to System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts, and just opening it will allow me to use my keyboard shortcuts once again.

What daemon is being run by the System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts link? and how can I enable it at startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because gnome-settings-daemon wasn't loaded in my startup programs. Have added it back in as an entry and now everything is working fine!